# dealing with 3 different user + admin user in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am getting into django and I am using drf to build a restful api but I have 4 different users
admin and he has access to admin panel
brokers who can do anything on the site but cannot access the admin panel
buyers who can only do 2 action buy and search
man in the middle who can do everything except one thing
the way I am doing right now is I have baseclass with all the shared fields between the users

```
class siteuser(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(
    max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    about = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and then I have 3 other models with the different fields and onetoone relation to the user model

```
class manger(siteuser):
    manger = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    manager_licsences_number = models.IntegerField()

class buyer(siteuser):
   buyer = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class seller(siteuser):
   seller = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   trust_number = models.IntegerField()
```

but I feel like this method is wrong I had to ideas in my head

1- i've been looking to creating my own abstract base class the user model and then using that model as my user model and using the admin panel for the admin user .

2- abstracting the user model 3 times and making 3 user objects and building custom oath for the three different users which I think is not a good approach

so what do you guys think is the best way to handle this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the user classes have special field, then maybe your approach is not so bad.But you can try this approach where using some sort of extra field, you can store data related to those special fields. For example:

```
class siteuser(models.Model):
    broker = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False, db_index = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, unique = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 254, null = False, blank = False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = 1)
    about = models.TextField()
    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)  #For special data

class manager(siteuser):
    class Meta:
       proxy = True

    @property
    def manager_licsences_number(self):
         return self.extra_field

    @manager_licsences_number.setter
    def manager_licsences_number(self, value):
        self.extra_field = value

   ...
```

Thus, you need not to create multiple tables for `manager`, `buyer`, `seller`. And saving mechanisom is simple:
     from myapp.models import manager

```
 m = manager()
 m.manager_licsences_number = '1-22-33-4'
 ..
 m.save()
 print(m.manager_licsences_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add one field "type" in siteuser and you don't have create 3 model "manger, buyer, seller"

```
class siteuser(models.Model):
    USER_CHOICE = (
        (1, 'manger'),
        (2, 'buyer'),
        (3, 'seller'),
    )
    broker = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False, db_index = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, unique = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 254, null = False, blank = False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = 1)
    about = models.TextField()
    type = models.ChoiceField(choices=USER_CHOICE)
```

Comment: i forgot to add this to the code but every user has a special field